# Bluetooth driver not working on an hp pavillion dv6 6155tx

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, hp, ralink

In my Hp Pavillion dv6 6155-tx everything is working just fine except for the Bluetooth. I have pretty much tried every bluetooth software out there but none seems to work. It seems that the driver is not installed or something like that. When i search for new devices it just dont find any device and the vice versa. Please kindly help me ! I am frustrated for more than 4 months now searching for some answers.

The output of rfkill list :-

> 0: hci0: Bluetooth

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

> 1: phy0: Wireless LAN

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

> 2: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

> 3: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: I had the same problem like Mr. Arin Chakraborty and tried a lot to fix it. But with his prescription, bluetooth starts like a magic. Thanks Mr. Arin. You made my day brother.

Comment: Glad it helped. You are very much welcome bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok finally i did some research and i was able to solve the mistery of the BLUETOOTH not working.

As per this - https://bugs.meego.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3498 the the radio was OFF all the time.

so to turn on the radio as they said - `sudo bccmd psset -s 0x0000 0x028c 0x0001`

and then i did - `sudo service bluetooth restart`

followed by a restart of the computer and then pressing the NETWORK BUTTON(f12) ON/OFF button twice to disable and then enable it and guess what it worked like a charm i can now connect everything.

Comment: It works for HP Pavilion g4. But I can't open the link to read the explanation. What does `bccmd` really do?

Answer (score 0):

Install synaptic form the Ubuntu Software Center

In Synaptic select **bcmwl-kernel-source** and **bcmwl-sta-source**

Then install it.

Comment: It Does not work, just an information that my bluetooth is ralink.

Comment: ralink ? im turkish i dont know what this word means .

Comment: ralink/motorola, it's the manufacturer of my bluetooth module.

Comment: i'm sorry it works for broadcom

Comment: Thnks anyways friend !