# Bluetooth adapter not found in HP Pavillion 15 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my HP Pavilion with dual boot alongside with Windows 8.

Bluetooth is not working in Ubuntu. No bluetooth icon in taskbar, at desktop by clicking an icon of bluetooth in system settings shows *no bluetooth adapter found*.

Comment: May be blocked in hardware or BIOS.  Type in `rfkill list` in a terminal and see what happens.  Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217530/bluetooth-driver-not-working-on-an-hp-pavillion-dv6-6155tx) out

Comment: I use a Pavilion 15-n240tx with Ubuntu 14.04.. `rfkill list` only shows the WiFi adapter. Not bluetooth.